# Ionic dynamic href Angular JS click event

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

So, I have a list of items in an Ionic framework project, like this:

```
 <a ng-repeat="item in items" href="#/item/{{item.id}}" ng-click="clicker(item)" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
```

Being a noob in AngularJS, I don't know how to generate random states using state providers. Urls look like this: /item/1, /item/2, /item/3, etc.

What am I trying to achieve:

- define a template
- load some content in that template, dynamically (for each item, i have different content)

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Do you mean "dynamic content" as the data from an AJAX call based on the id or just static HTML files?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal For the moment that's not important. I'm trying to just open a new "page" when i click a list item. After that, passing the id must be easy, i guess. Right now just static html files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible. First take a bit look about defining state and using state manager https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Now, define a state like:

```
.state('itemView', {
    url: '/item/:id',
    templateUrl : function($stateParams) {
        // Your path to the view
        return 'views/items/display' + $stateParams.id + '.html';
    }
})
```

Now your click on anchor link should render the page based on the id considering you have static HTML files named as `views/items/display1.html`

Comment: Thank you. The page is not rendering, but I understood the idea. Clicking on an item right now, does nothing.

Comment: Glad this helps! The documentation of `ui-router` is pretty good. Please try to read it from the start, you will definitely make your page running.